# MySQL Insert from one column to another if not exist

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I have a table, `products` with the columns `description` and `description_short`
Some of my products has `description` empty and `description_short` filled and vice versa, some might even have both filled. So what I want to do is to copy all of the filled `description` to `description_short` where `description_short` is empty.

What would be the easiest way to do this with MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

It is simple:

```
update products 
set description = description_short
where description is null; 

commit;

update products 
set description_short = description
where description_short is null; 

commit;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update table_name 
set description_short =description 
where description_short is null and description is not null
```